# Less ambiguous phrase than "digitally challenged" for someone missing fingers

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, euphemisms

I'd like to use "digitally challenged" to refer to someone who is missing part or all of a finger, but it sounds like I'm talking about someone who doesn't know how to use computers. Are there any phrases, ideally somewhat humorous in nature, that I can use to refer to people who are missing part or all of a finger?

Example usage:

> Steer clear of that izakaya. I've heard some of the patrons are [alternative to "digitally challenged"].

Comment: Why would patrons with missing fingers be a reason to avoid an izakaya?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet They're probably yakusa members, Japanese gangsters.

Comment: @Jacinto Oh yeah, that would make sense, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

If you lack one eye you’re one-eyed, and if you lack one leg you’re one-legged. It then stands to reason that if you lack one finger you’re **nine-fingered**.

And people have used this before. Here's Sam talking to Frodo, who had lost a finger in a fight (emphasis mine in all quotes):

> ‘What a tale we have been in, Mr. Frodo, haven’t we?’ he said. ‘I wish I could hear it told! Do you think they’ll say: *Now comes the story of **Nine-fingered Frodo** and the Ring of Doom*? And then everyone will hush […]’ [(J. R. R. Tolkien, *The Return of The King*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=QBWbp55jP4YC&q=%22Now%20comes%20the%20story%20of%20Nine-fingered%20Frodo%22&dq=%22Now%20comes%20the%20story%20of%20Nine-fingered%20Frodo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiskfKovoL2AhX6iv0HHUUlDOwQ6AF6BAgIEAI)

After that they gave Frodo the title “Nine-fingered”, says [The Encyclopedia of ARDA](https://www.glyphweb.com/arda/n/ninefingered.php).

Of course that was in Middle Earth. Back on our Earth, Chishō Takaoka (1896-1944), a geisha who chopped off one of her fingers to make some sort of point, became internationally famous as the [“Nine-fingered Geisha” (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chish%C5%8D_Takaoka). And Japanese [yakusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakuza) gangsters that chop off one of their own fingers, presumably of the sort that haunt your izakaya, are often referred to as *nine-fingered*:

> He employs a bodyguard who doubles as a chauffeur, **an ex-yakuza who cut off his pinkie finger** years ago as a gesture of apology to a gang superior. Adelstein says he needs a car and a **nine-fingered driver** in order to avoid the subway, where a hit man might shove him in front of a train. [(Peter Hessler, “All Due Respect,” *The New Yorker*, Jan 9, 2012.)](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/01/09/all-due-respect)
>
> Despite the folklore surrounding groups, the modern-day yakuza are entrepreneurs, rather than the tattooed, **nine-fingered thugs** in white suits wielding samurai swords of popular imagination; [(Jake Adelstein, “Mobsters on a mission: How Japan’s mafia launched an aid effort”, *Independent*, 8 April 2011.)](http://%5B(Jake%20Adelstein,%20%E2%80%9CMobsters%20on%20a%20mission:%20How%20Japan%E2%80%99s%20mafia%20launched%20an%20aid%20effort%E2%80%9D,%20*Independent*,%208%20April%202011.))

If someone lacks more than one finger you could just adjust the number: *an eight-fingered pianist, a seven-fingered shark handler*. If an indeterminate number of fingers are missing, perhaps *single-digit-fingered*?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the loanword *sans* (without):

> Steer clear of that izakaya. I've heard some of the patrons are *sans* fingers.

Perhaps the most famous use of *sans* comes from Shakespeare ("All the world's a stage" from *As You Like It*):

> Last scene of all,
>   That ends this strange eventful history,
>   Is second childishness and mere oblivion,
>   Sans teeth, sans eyes, sans taste, sans everything.

[Oxford Living Dictionaries: sans](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sans)

[Wikipedia: All the world's a stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_world%27s_a_stage)

Answer (score 1):

What about **[fingerless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fingerless)**:

> Steer clear of that izakaya. I've heard some of the patrons are **fingerless**.

This doesn't imply that the person has only lost one finger, but you could qualify it by saying *partially fingerless*.

Answer (score 1):

The Japanese term is [Yubitsume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yubitsume) and it could be understood by Anglophones if they were exposed to Japanese manga and movies as many of them depict it.

When I lived in Japan, it was not uncommon to see a person with an *amputated* finger. I used the term "shortened finger" and it was perfectly understood by Anglophones and Japanese to mean a person who underwent Yubitsume. Your example:

> Steer clear of that izakaya. I've heard some of the patrons have a shortened finger.